# Execute Lambda from AWS SSM Automation with Parameters

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, automation, aws-lambda

I currently have a lambda function that updates a DynamoDB table with a value passed as a parameter. I am able to run the following within the Lambda console with a test parameter set to `"TEST"`:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    update_ami(event)


def update_ami(ami_id):
    #DO STUFF
```

I am attempting to call this from an SSM Automation built from the following JSON document:

```
{  
   "description":"Test Execute Lambda Function.",
   "schemaVersion":"0.3",
   "assumeRole":"MYARN",
   "parameters":{},
   "mainSteps":[  
        {
            "name": "invokeMyLambdaFunction",
            "action": "aws:invokeLambdaFunction",
            "maxAttempts": 3,
            "timeoutSeconds": 120,
            "onFailure": "Abort",
            "inputs": {
                "FunctionName": "MyLambdaFunction",
                "Payload": "TESTER"

            }
        }
   ]
}
```

Executing this automation results in the following error:

```
Automation Step Execution fails when it is invoking the lambda function. Get Exception from Invoke API of lambda Service. Exception Message from Invoke API: [Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'TESTER': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
```

I have also tried passing the `Payload` input as a JSON object instead of a string, and adjusted my lambda method accordingly:

JSON Automation:

```
...
    "inputs": {
         "FunctionName": "MyLambdaFunction",
         "Payload": {
             "ami_id": "AMI-TESTER"
         }  
    }
...
```

Lambda Python:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    update_ami(event['ami-id'])
```

This results in the following error coming from the Automation Document editor within the SSM console:

```
Input {ami_id=TESTER} is of type class java.util.LinkedHashMap, but expected type is String.
```

So in a nutshell... How do I pass a single string from an Automation document to a Lambda Function?

Answer (score 1):

The error which is shown below looks to be issue with payload not passed as string:

```
Input {ami_id=TESTER} is of type class java.util.LinkedHashMap, but expected type is String
```

Please try to use escape character before double quotes.

```
    "inputs": {
             "FunctionName": "MyLambdaFunction",
             "Payload": "{
                 \"ami_id\": \"AMI-TESTER\"
             }"  
        }
```

AWS has provided proper syntax, if you see [this Url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-simpatch.html#automation-pet1)

```
  {
     "name":"updateSsmParam",
     "action":"aws:invokeLambdaFunction",
     "timeoutSeconds":1200,
     "maxAttempts":1,
     "onFailure":"Abort",
     "inputs":{
        "FunctionName":"Automation-UpdateSsmParam",
        "Payload":"{\"parameterName\":\"latestAmi\", \"parameterValue\":\"{{createImage.ImageId}}\"}"
     }
  }
```